# How can I see the javac command IntelliJ IDEA uses to compile my code?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javac

When I write a Java code in IntelliJ IDEA and runs it, IntelliJ compiles the Java file, a class file is extracted and then the class file is run.

How can I see the javac command line that IntelliJ runs. I ask it so I can see whether IntelliJ adds some flags to the javac command.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't run `javac`, therefore you can't see the command line.

Compiler API is used directly from Java code. If you [enable debug logging](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for `build.log` file, you may find some more details how the modified and dependent files are compiled and what options are used.

Sample debug log line:

```
[  41011]  DEBUG - s.incremental.java.JavaBuilder - Compiling chunk [stopme] with options: "-g -deprecation -proceedOnError -encoding UTF-8 -source 1.8 -target 1.8 -proc:none"
```

Comment: By the way, Eclipse runs javac ?

Comment: Not an expert in Eclipse, please submit a separate question.

Comment: What is the "Compiler API"? I couldn't find SDK documentation mentioning it.

Comment: @flow2k Check JDK documentation, API resides in tools.jar.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks. I found out that IntelliJ is itself written in Java and runs in a customized JVM called "JetBrains Runtime" (https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/). Anyways, IntelliJ will dynamically load a compiler class from the user-specified JDK's tools.jar, and use that class to compile sources? Am I right?

Answer (score 6):

IDEA is not running java binary, so there is no way to see the commands. Instead, IDEA uses Java compiler API directly.

> If you want a raw representation of what is done to build the project,
>   you can use Build | Generate Ant build. Examine the build file or run
>   it from the command line via Ant to see what happens and what
>   options/commands are invoked.

Answer (score 2):

Look in `/Users/itsabhiaryan/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2017.1/build-log`

When you build inside IDEA, it writes a log to build.log in this directory.

IDEA is not running java binary, so there is no way to see the commands.