# How do you determine the compile commands being issued by IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

I am using IntelliJ Idea to compile a simple 2-file Kotlin project. I would prefer to use the command line to compile and run. So I would like to see what commands the IDE is issuing to compile and run the project. How would I do that?

Comment: @tynn For IntelliJ I am using whatever the default is. For compiling at the command line, I would not be using Gradle.

Comment: @tynn Nope, no build.gradle file.

Comment: @tynn IntelliJ does allow the generation of an Ant file: Build->Generate Ant Build . I don't understand all that is in there, but I notice that there is no "kotlinc" anywhere.

Comment: You can't see the commands because IntelliJ IDEA doesn't call the compiler process, it uses compiler API directly. The same applies to both Java and Kotlin, therefore your question already [has the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43855256/104891).

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation for using the command line compiler? https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html

Comment: @JKLy Yes, I did see that. I wish there was an example of making a project with multiple files/packages and then compiling and running that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by CrazyCoder above and [as an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855119/how-can-i-see-the-javac-command-intellij-idea-uses-to-compile-my-code/43855256#43855256) IntelliJ does not call command line programs to build an application, but rather makes calls to a compiler API.

Also mentioned [as an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43855119/how-can-i-see-the-javac-command-intellij-idea-uses-to-compile-my-code/43855256#43855256) is the fact that IntelliJ IDEA has a way to export a file for **Ant** to process: **Build->Generate Ant Build...** . That output file can be examined, or Ant can be invoked to process it, in order to see what commands need to be run.

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to use `kotlinc` to compile your 2 files, you would do something like this:

**example.kt**

```
fun say() {
    println("hello world")
}
```

**main.kt**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    say()
}
```

Then run this to compile your files into a directory called `classes/`:

```
kotlinc main.kt example.kt -d classes
```

And this to run it:

```
kotlin -classpath classes MainKt
```

Comment: Thanks! How does that run without the adding the kotlin runtime to the compile command that they say you need to do on their kotlinc page? I guess "kotlin" includes that (while "java" does not)?

Comment: Yes, the `kotlin` command runs it with the packaged kotlin-runtime on the classpath. The `java` command doesn't know anything about Kotlin, so you would either have to include the runtime on the classpath yourself, or compile it with `-include-runtime`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but an easy way to get the compiler command line I know of is to run a Gradle build of your project with debug log level:

```
./gradlew compileKotlin --debug | grep 'compiler args'
```

You'll get something like this:

> 14:23:57.754 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.Project] [KOTLIN] Kotlin **compiler args**: -d C:\yourProjectPath\build\kotlin-classes\main -cp  -no-stdlib -no-reflect -module C:\Temp\kjps1937184266353217163kotlingradlepluginapi.script.xml -module-name kotlin-gradle-plugin-api -jvm-target 1.6 -Xadd-compiler-builtins -Xload-builtins-from-dependencies -language-version 1.1 -api-version 1.1 -Xcoroutines=warn

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't know about or use gradle, but I do have it on my system. However, no gradlew and I see it is called the Gradle Wrapper and that "If a Gradle project has set up the Wrapper (and we recommend all projects do so), you can execute the build using one of the following commands from the root of the project: ". I am guessing that IntelliJ Idea has not created a Gradle project.